# Where do i put the files I download for Laravel packages?

Tags: php, laravel, download, generator, package

(I use Laravel 5.0). I am trying to add the generators package and would like to add more packages, but I don't know, where to save the downloaded files. There is no installation file that comes with it. I have downloaded the files for the package from the following website https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended, but it does not tell me where to put the files on my computer. When I try to install this using composer and typing in:

```
composer laracasts/generators --dev
```

I get the error:

> "Command "laracasts/generators is not defined".

Where do I go from here? I would like to get this package installed, but I am stuck and I feel like I am not getting all the information I need to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with composer require laracasts/generators --dev

Comment: thanks, for some reason i completely missed the word "require". after adding that it seemed to complete the task by itself.  so i am deleting the files that i downloaded directly from the website.  it seems that this command will take care of the installation for me.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the readme tells you everything you need to know. when you're in the home folder of your laravel project with a terminal or something type

```
composer require laracasts/generators --dev
```

after that

Step 2: Add the Service Provider

You'll only want to use these generators for local development, so you don't want to update the production providers array in config/app.php. Instead, add the provider in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php, like so:

```
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
        $this->app->register('Laracasts\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider');
    }
}
```

after that just run php artisan. all of this information is right in the link you're showing us

Answer (score 0):

You should have a composer.json in your Laravel folder.

You want to edit this file.

You should find a line like so :

```
{
    "require": {
         "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

Add a line like so :

```
{
    "require": {
         "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*",
         "alarmists/generators": "*"
    }
}
```

Then run cmd : php composer.phar install

There you go, it'll install everything.

Also, please note that the composer command you wrote is wrong compared to the link you gave. 
The link actually shows 
    composer require laracasts/generators --dev

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually download packages in order to install them.

Ensure you have composer installed on your system.

At the root of your project where you have this file `composer.json` simply run:

`composer require laracasts/generators --dev`

or

Simply add the package to your composer.json under `require` and run `composer update` command at your terminal